# AWS RDS + Magento 2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, magento, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I'm currently trying to run Magento 2 using two services from AWS:

1. Elastic Beanstalk - Multi-container Docker
2. RDS (MySQL)

Here are the following steps taken in order to create and run the environment:

1. So I started by creating the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file which includes a magento 2 image and a phpmyadmin image. Of course I also have a docker-compose.yml file.
2. I upload both files zipped and the `Health` checks as `Ok` - good sign
3. I create the RDS MySQL DB Instance and take note of the pass, name and username in order to apply it in the configuration under Elastic Beanstalk
4. I create a Security Group and associate both Elastic Beanstalk and RDS like this they can communicate with each other
5. I setup all the environment variables in the `Configuration` tab under the Elastic Beanstalk Service

So far so good, no sign of errors...

**The Problem**

Going through the "Wizard" provided by Magento 2 is where lies the problem. I cannot get passed `Step 2` - Add a Database. I keep bumping into that error:

`Database 'magento2' does not exist or specified database server user does not have privileges to access this database.`

- I know the database exists, I think the problem is with the privileges

Recall I setup all the environment variables, I am assuming that it will work.

**Additional Info**

I have no problem running it locally via my docker-composer.yml and env files

**Resources**

https://hub.docker.com/r/alexcheng/magento2/

I'm stuck and cannot find a solution to my problem. Would be great if someone has a solution to that problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out that it was a permission issue - I need to set `Enable IAM` option when creating the RDS DB Instance... I will leave the steps if in any case someone wants to refer to it. I can help out of needed